# PHP: не находит функцию

Tags: функции, php

Есть файл functions.php, который находиться в папке system. В файл function.php включается(once) файл config.php, в нем обычное подключение к бд, рабочее. Так же есть папка manager в этой папке файл settings.php, в файл settings я включаю файл functions.php. Файл включается все хорошо. Вопрос: Почему php не видит функцию в файле functions.php.

Functions.php

```
function filtervariable ($variable, $type) {

    switch(gettype($variable)) {
        case "integer":
            $variable = settype($variable, "integer");
            $variable = intval($variable);
            break;
        case "string":
            $variable = settype($variable, "string");
            $variable = strval($variable);
            break;
        case "boolean":
            $variable = settype($variable, "boolean");
            $variable = boolval($variable);
            break; }

    switch($type) {
        case "integer" or "int":
            $variable = settype($variable, "integer");
            $variable = intval($variable);
            break;
        case "string" or "str":
            $variable = settype($variable, "string");
            $variable = strval($variable);
            break;
        case "boolean" or "bool":
            $variable = settype($variable, "boolean");
            $variable = boolval($variable);
            break;

    }

    return $variable;

}
```

P.S. Пишу в PhpStorm 7. При наведение на имя функции в файле settings.php, пишет: Underfined function filtervariable...

Comment: > Вопрос: Почему php не видит функцию в файле functions.php.

у вас все-таки шторм не работает или php?

Comment: @Etki, у меня в название файла в конце скрытая точка стояла. 
То есть functions.php, а на самом деле было functions.php.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

либо не правильный путь, либо не правильно обращаетесь) одно из двух.